# Firebase functions react on a firestore create event

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
export const onCommentCreated = functions.firestore.document('Comment/{gameName}/{post}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('Gamefeed').doc(context.params.gameName).collection('Posts').doc(context.params.post)
    docRef.update({
            amountOfComments: 99
        }).then(response => {
            return
        }).catch(error => {
            return
        })
})
```

This is the function i am trying to deploy to firebase. Somehow this does not work. Because i get

```
functions: failed to create function onCommentCreated
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. I followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events as a reference point when creating this function.

I can add that i tried to remove the contents of the function and just added a return statement. Still the deployment dosen't work. So my guess is that something is wrong with the line

```
export const onCommentCreated = functions.firestore.document('Comment/{gameName}/{post}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```

Comment: Make sure your Firebase CLI is up to date.  Then edit your question to show the relevant parts of the error log file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening on collection.

You should listen on the document creation, so it should be

```
exports.onCommentCreated = functions.firestore.document('Comment/{gameName}/{post}/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```